# Filling area under a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to fill the area under a function using the package tikz? Only tikz. Is it possible?
This is what I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin, gray!30, step=1 cm](-4.9,-3.9) grid (4.9,3.9);

\draw [thick] [->] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right, below] {$x$};
 \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
   \draw[xshift=\x cm, thick] (0pt,-1pt)--(0pt,1pt) node[below] {$\x$};

\draw [thick] [->] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above, left] {$y$};
 \foreach \y in {-3,...,3}
   \draw[yshift=\y cm, thick] (-1pt,0pt)--(1pt,0pt) node[left] {$\y$};

\draw [domain=-2:2, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {\x*\x}) node[right] at (1.5,2) {$f(x)=x^2$};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Please tell me, how do I fill the area under the function I drew? I mean the area between x axis and the curve.

Answer (score 31):

The same `plot` command can be used to construct a path for the filled area:

```
\fill [gray, domain=-2:2, variable=\x]
  (-2, 0)
  -- plot ({\x}, {\x*\x})
  -- (2, 0)
  -- cycle;
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thin, gray!30, step=1 cm](-4.9,-3.9) grid (4.9,3.9);

    \fill [gray, domain=-2:2, variable=\x]
      (-2, 0)
      -- plot ({\x}, {\x*\x})
      -- (2, 0)
      -- cycle;

    \draw [thick] [->] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right, below] {$x$};
     \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
       \draw[xshift=\x cm, thick] (0pt,-1pt)--(0pt,1pt) node[below] {$\x$};

    \draw [thick] [->] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above, left] {$y$};
     \foreach \y in {-3,...,3}
       \draw[yshift=\y cm, thick] (-1pt,0pt)--(1pt,0pt) node[left] {$\y$};

    \draw [domain=-2:2, variable=\x]
      plot ({\x}, {\x*\x}) node[right] at (1.5,2) {$f(x)=x^2$};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 14):

<sub>This solution requires a recent version of the `pgfplots` package, >=1.10.</sub>

You could also use the plotting capabilities of the `pgfplots` package and its library `fillbetween` that lets you fill the area between two generic curves.

First, you draw the curve that you want to plot and you assign a name to it. Then, you insert the x axis as a “fictional” curve, that is actually plotted but not drawn, and you name it, too.

Finally, you shade the area below your curve issuing a third `\addplot` command.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    grid=major,
    ymin=-5,
    no marks,
    ]
    \addplot+[smooth,blue,name path=A] {x*x}; % actual curve
    \addplot+[draw=none,name path=B] {0};     % “fictional” curve
    \addplot+[gray] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-4:4}]; % filling
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]