# Shading area under curve TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using code I got from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242311/filling-area-under-a-function), I'm trying to make a small rectangle of height `y = 6` between bounds `x = 2` and `x = 7`, and shade it in.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=0, ymax=10, ytick={0,2,...,10}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=0, xmax=10, xtick={0,2,...,10}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]
    \addplot[domain=2:7,blue,name path=A] {6}; % actual curve
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B] {0};     % “fictional” curve
    \addplot[gray] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=2:7}]; %filling
\addplot+[
      blue,very thick,dotted,
      mark=none,
      const plot,
      empty line=jump,
]
coordinates {
    (2,0)
    (2,6)

    (7,0)
    (7,6)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because the domain `domain=-pi:pi`, which you set in the axis options, is used for the plot named `B`. If you add the appropriate domain for that plot, it works as expected.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=0, ymax=10, ytick={0,2,...,10}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=0, xmax=10, xtick={0,2,...,10}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]
    \addplot[domain=2:7,blue,name path=A] {6}; % actual curve
    \addplot[draw=none,name path=B,domain=2:7] {0}; 

\addplot[gray] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=2:7}]; %filling
\addplot+[
      blue,very thick,dotted,
      mark=none,
      const plot,
      empty line=jump,
]
coordinates {
    (2,0)
    (2,6)

    (7,0)
    (7,6)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Just to show Stefan Pinnow that his proposal is certainly not the simplest one. This code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
  ymin=0, ymax=10, ytick={0,2,...,10}, ylabel=$f(x)$,
  xmin=0, xmax=10, xtick={0,2,...,10}, xlabel=$x$,
  domain=-pi:pi,samples=101, % added
]

    \fill[gray] (2,0) rectangle (7,6);

\addplot+[
      blue,very thick,dotted,
      mark=none,
      const plot,
      empty line=jump,
]
coordinates {
    (2,0)
    (2,6)

    (7,0)
    (7,6)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields the same output. But this is *not* the point of the discussion. The point, I think, is that your code yields an unexpected (or "funky" as they were called before the edit) results. To shade a rectangle, you do not need even pgfplots, actually not even Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 1):

As marmot already pointed out in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453856/95441) what causes the mess is that path *B* has the wrong `domain`. The simplest way to get what you want is to set the `domain` in the `axis` options (only) and remove it everywhere else.

But to simply draw a rectangle you don't need the `fillbetween` library. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ytick={0,2,...,10},
        ylabel=$f(x)$,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=10,
        xtick={0,2,...,10},
        xlabel=$x$,
        domain=2:7, % <-- adapted to the "right" bounds
        samples=2,  % <-- (for straight lines 2 is enough)
    ]

        % alternative without using the `fillbetween' library
        \addplot [fill=red,opacity=0.5] coordinates { (2,6) (7,6) }
            \closedcycle
        ;

        \addplot [blue,name path=A] {6};
        \addplot [draw=none,name path=B] {0};
        \addplot [gray] fill between [
            of=A and B,
%            soft clip={domain=2:7}     % <-- not needed any more now
        ];

        \addplot+ [
              blue,very thick,dotted,
              mark=none,
              const plot,
              empty line=jump,
        ] coordinates {
            (2,0)
            (2,6)

            (7,0)
            (7,6)
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Well, sure, you do not need pgfplots to draw as square. However, my impression was that the OP was kind enough to cut out everything that is not relevant to the problem, and will in the end make use of the `domain=-pi:pi` and samples for the things that do require pgfplots. In that case, the changes you made may not be too helpful. Of course, if the OP only wants to draw a square, (s)he will be fine with that, but this can be done with a simple `\fill` command, too.

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of ways to draw a (simple) rectangle. And that is exactly what OP was searching for. The main reason for my answer was to show an alternative to the `fillbetween` which is kind of overkill for that simple task. And as you can see, I have drawn this without using `domain`. And of course also `\fill [gray] (axis:cs:2,0) rectangle (axis cs:7,6);` would have been another possibility to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yes, that's why the question is not "How can one fill a square" but "Shading area under curve TikZ"....

Comment: That's the title, but in the text ...

Comment: Well, this can go on forever. How about someone adds a 3-line code that just fills a square and says both of us have missed that simple possibility? Again, my take is that the OP uses pgfplots and sets the domain and samples for a reason....

Comment: I love "discussing" with you ... I never said your solution is not valid. Nor did I say mine is the best in the world. The user asks (in the text) for filling a rectangle and I provided "another possibility" where I also nowhere stated that is the simplest possible one. If OP didn't want to fill a rectangle (at least) I wouldn't write it and would provide an MWE that is much nearer to the "real" problem. End of discussion from my side.